# React-native network request always fails

Tags: http, networking, react-native

I had a working project, that has worked for the past 3 weeks.  All of a sudden,  out of nowhere, the fetch requests have stopped working.

I haven't run any update or npm installs.  So I'm lost as to what could be the cause of this.

my fetch request is pretty standard.  Simplified here with a console.log instead of setState in the response.

```
fetch("https://54fd510.ngrok.io/api/v1")
.then((response)=>response.json())
.then((responseData)=>{
  console.log(responseData);
}).done();
```

All I get now whenever doing any sort of request, 
 is "Network Request Failed" with...
 onload. _sendload, setReadyState as the stack trace items.

Infact any and all my fetch requests in the app arent working.

So I tried boiling it down, and just created a new blank app.
With only a button and a fetch request linked to the button. To make sure it has nothing to do with my particular app.  And this request fails as well.

So it appears its react-native itself that is failing, it isn't anything to do with my code.

No matter what I try, the network request is always failing. 
Tried downgrading, and get the same.

Really lost as to where to look now.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure your ngrok pipe is working? iOS or Android, or both? Simulator or device, or both?

Comment: Ngrok works.  At first I had a CORS error, which I thought was obviously the problem.  But then I fixed that server side, and the problem still persists.  Im using Android real, and emulator.  Both dont work.   I then tried just a basic test endpoint using http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/, and that didn't work either.  The test endpoint however, hangs for about 4 seconds, and then comes back with a fail.   So at least thats something.  The last thing to try, is to downgrade to a version where you had to require('fetch'), just to see if somehow thats the culprit

Comment: @KyleK found out the error? I am facing the same issue. Running my nodejs backend on localhost

Comment: Hi , I am facing the same issue