# React-Native fetch, Network request failed. Not using localhost

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

I have an app, which I'm using fetch to authenticate user. It was working until few days ago and I haven't change anything. Just upgraded from react 0.27 to 0.28, not fetch is not working.

I have searched for almost 2 days and I have read almost all questions in Stack Overflow. Most of users trying to fetch something from localhost, and when they change it to actual IP address, they get it to work.
But I'm not fetching anything from localhost, also mine code used to be working.

Here is my code:

```
fetch('http://somesite.com/app/connect', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'language':'en-US',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        uid: uid,
        refresh_token: refresh_token,
        token: access_token,
        device: device_id,
        device_name: device_name,
      })
    })
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseData) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(responseData.body))
})
.catch((err)=> {
  console.log('Some errors occured');
  console.log(err);
})
.done();
```

I tried to make some new projects, simple, just used a simple fetch example fro tutorials, it gave same error. I tried to open my website which I'm trying to connect to it, through browser in emulator, it works, but it seems through my, app cannot connect to any website/IP. It gives this error in Chrome console:

```
TypeError: Network request failed
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=true:28193:8)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=true:14591:15)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=true:29573:6)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=true:29431:6)
    at http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=true:29506:52
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=true:13428:23)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=true:11999:23)
    at http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=true:11906:8
    at guard (http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=true:11857:1)
    at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=true:11905:1)
```

Actually I have the same problem as this user here: [React-native network request always fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36126793/react-native-network-request-always-fails)

info.plist from xcode:
[image: info.plist from xcode]

Comment: What do you have under `NSAppTransportSecurity` in your info.plist file for your app?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i have added screenshot to main post. also you can see it here http://i.stack.imgur.com/vvqMk.png

Comment: @Ataomega Have you tried restarting your computer?? I was having this same issue and just a simple restart fixed it.

Comment: really i dont remember how many times i have restarted my computer. after any change i did it. reseting emulator, restarting computer ... reinstalling react native and ...

Comment: after 3 days, finally problem solved by downgrading the react native.

Comment: Facing the same issue!

Comment: @Ataomega omg, i'm not gonna downgrade for that :(

Comment: what about android? I am facing same issue in android as well.

Comment: @Ataomega what version of RN have you downgraded to, I am facing same error on android with RN 0.49.3

Comment: thank god I downgraded to 0.45.2, wasted my whole day seeing those change ip address solution

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You should check out this link: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8118

Looks like the issue emerged in React Native 0.28. Solution is to "Allow Arbitrary Loads" in the info.plist file found in the ios>build folder that React creates.

If you open the entire ios folder in xcode, then open this info.plist file you can create a new key to Allow Arbitrary Loads and it should fix your issue.

[image: Allow Arbitrary Loads]

Comment: @Ataomega how did you fixed that problem. I am facing the same in andriod

Comment: @Carlos did you resolve the issue on Android?  I'm running into the same issue, on RN 0.35, Android API 21

Comment: @BenYee: I replaced localhost with my ip address and start working fine

Comment: what about android? I am facing same issue in android as well.

Comment: everyone is mentioning to change ip address, but what if we using rest api from server and don't know its ip.

Comment: Cannot use the  the IP address of an https server, or the server's certificate won't work (is domain-specific).  What is the fix?  Is cannot be that React-Native cannot be used to connect to any remote resources, unless they can be fetched with a static-ip address in place of the domain-name - so there must be a solution.  Maybe an alternative to "fetch()" ??

Comment: Any idea for android?

Comment: I have solved my anroid network error problem with https in react native. 
Please check my gist. https://gist.github.com/ecdundar/f9207775e4cf22e939f77c5307265529

Answer (score 0):

Set the info.plist doesn't work for me too. Trying to run on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is the code is trying to fetch HTTP endpoint instead of HTTPS, which is not encouraged. If you are fetching from localhost server, an easy solution will be exposing your localhost server through a [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) https endpoint.

Steps:

1. Download ngrok and run `ngrok http 8081` from terminal/cmd, where you should change 8081 to your localhost service port.
2. Ngrok will give you a https forwarding endpoint, simply use that to access your localhost server.