# React-Native Network Request Failed only in HTTPS

Tags: ssl, react-native

This code works perfectly fine for a few months:

```
try {
    return await fetch(url + '/api/v2/login?'+param).then((response) => {
        return response.json()
    });
}
catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message)
}
```

But last week, react-native throws an error "Network Request Failed".
I'm sure that our API is working because I already have tested it in a few online API Tester.

And when I didn't force the HTTPS, and just the HTTP, it works.

And our current react version is: 0.41

Here is the error:

```
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (fetch.js:441)
at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (event-target.js:172)
at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (XMLHttpRequest.js:546)
at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (XMLHttpRequest.js:381)
at XMLHttpRequest.js:485
at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (EventEmitter.js:181)
at MessageQueue.__callFunction (MessageQueue.js:266)
at MessageQueue.js:103
at MessageQueue.__guard (MessageQueue.js:231)
at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (MessageQueue.js:102)
```

Comment: Which platform did this problem occurred?

Comment: In Android. Also, I'm fetching from our cloud server, no changes on both sides. The error just suddenly occur.

Comment: Have you added Internet permission in the AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: Last thing, I have created a latest react version app and test this code, and it works! So, Does it have something to do with the react-native version ?

Comment: It is possible, by the way, what android version are you on? Because Android 7.0 has a different configuration

Comment: Yes, it is included in the AndroidManifest.xml

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: I have tested it in an emulator (marshmallow), real android phone (Nougat). And additionally, when I didn't force the HTTPS, and just connect to the HTTP, it also works.

Comment: Can you stacktrace the error?

Comment: Additionally, please check if your server cert is correctly configured here https://www.digicert.com/help/

Comment: I edited my posted question and included the error. And I checked our url, the digicert said:
SSL Certificate is correctly installed.
Congratulations! This certificate is correctly installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the look of this, this is most likely an issue of `react-native`. You may want to test around with different `react-native` version against different android version. Here's some thread from other users who's having the same problem, most of them resorted with upgrading `react-native` version. Remember, technically `react-native` is not a fully grown product yet, so some errors are to be expected.

[React Native fetch() Network Request Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38418998/react-native-fetch-network-request-failed)

[React-native fetch() from https server with self-signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36289125/react-native-fetch-from-https-server-with-self-signed-certificate)

[React-Native fetch, Network request failed. not using localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38077273/react-native-fetch-network-request-failed-not-using-localhost)

Comment: Just an update. To solve this problem, I have to upgrade the react-native version at least 0.46