# How can i reach other computer api react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, android-emulator

im developing my react native app on MAC and im developing my API from my windows pc.

when im try to reach api from mac with postman i can use

but when i try to send request to api from react-native app (ios or android emulator) it cant reach.

postman request is:
Method GET
http://192.168.1.109:5000/api/pk/get
it returns data on MAC successfully

when i trying to code below:

```
fetch("http://192.168.1.109:5000/api/pk/get").then(response=>{console.log(response.json())})
```

it gives NETWORK REQUEST FAILED error.

how can i make this connection on same network two devices
(Actually it work on postman. how can i make reach react-native app to other pc API)

Comment: Since you aren't using https you probably need to disable ATS in your iOS app

Answer (score 0):

The `.json()` method is asynchronous. You need to add another callback to handle the data from the resolved promise. Change it to this:

```
fetch("http://192.168.1.109:5000/api/pk/get")
   .then(response => {
    response.json()
        .then(data => console.log(data))
    }
```

You'll likely also need to enable HTTP for iOS. Add this to your info.plist file

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key> 
    <dict>     
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>     
        <true/> 
    </dict>
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38077273/react-native-fetch-network-request-failed-not-using-localhost/38219454#38219454) answer for info on how to do it through XCode.

Comment: didnt worked :(

Comment: Edited my answer with another thing you should do

Comment: i tried that too but didnt worked. also i added to NSExceptionDomains my local ip it didnt worked too

Comment: i tried add my local ip to exception domains  but it didnt worked too. safari browser can reach, postman can reach but react native app cant reach this ip :(